# Array of objects of different types

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, types

I'm programming a game as Java applet, and I have two different classes with similar variables - `Pavement` and `Way`.

I would like to create an Array that will contain objects from both classes. I have to change for example `x` and `y` of all these objects so I would like to create an `Array`. Is this possible to do?

I have tried `ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();` but if I `obj.add(0, theWay);` I can't find a way to read variables.

I also tried `System.out.print(obj.get(0));` and got `rpg.way@2c61bbb7`.

Comment: You're using an `ArrayList`, not an array. How do the classes `Pavement` and `Way` look? Please add their code to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you would like to call a method (like `setX()`) on a Way instance, or on a Pavement instance, without knowing if the object is a Way or a Pavement.

This is exactly the problem that polymorphism solves. Define an interface `Locatable`, and make your two classes implement this interface. Then create a `List<Locatable>`, and you'll be able to add Ways and Pavements inside it:

```
public interface Locatable {
    public void setX(int x);
    public void setY(int y);

    public int getX();
    public int getY();
}

public class Way implements Locatable {
    ...
}

public class Pavement implements Locatable {
    ...
}

List<Locatable> locatables = new ArrayList<Locatable>();
list.add(new Way());
list.add(new Pavement());
for (Locatable locatable: locatables) {
    locatable.setX(22);
    locatable.setY(43);
}

for (Locatable locatable: locatables) {
    System.out.println("the locatable is an instance of " + locatable.getClass());
    System.out.println("its location is " + locatable.getX() + ", " + locatable.getY());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ArrayList<Object>` and you check the type of the objects.

For instance:

```
ArrayList<Object> L = new ArrayList<Object>();
//..add objects
for (Object o : L){
    if(o.getClass() == Class1.class){
        Class1 obj1 = (Class1) o;
        //...
    }else if(o.getClass() == Class2.class){
        Class2 obj2 = (Class2) o;
        //...
    }else{
        //...
    }
}
```

You can also use `instanceof` to check the type.

Comment: Well i did not meant that. I would like to put for example 10 objects of way and 10 objects of pavement into one array to have access to x and y variables. Co you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You mention the classes are different but similar? If the classes are similar enough that you want to try calling the same methods on the classes, you may want to consider generalizing the classes using an abstract class: This is much better practice than the "instance of" and caste solution. You could also use an interface, but the abstract class allows you to actually implement changeX() and changeY() if they work the same way. For example, if you want to call changeX(int x) or changeY(int y) on either of the objects regardless of whether they are `Way` or `Pavement` objects, you probably want to do something like this:

```
public abstract class Changeable
{
    public void changeX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void changeY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
}

public Class Pavement extends Changeable{ ... }

public Class Way extends Changeable{ ... }
```

At which point you can create an array of the interface and insert objects inside like so:

```
List<Changeable> paths = new ArrayList<Changeable>();
paths.add(new Way());
paths.add(new Pavement());
Changeable path = paths.get(0);
path.changeX(5);
path.changeY(7);
```